# iPhone data transmission issue

Tags: iphone, mysql, sql, objective-c

I have an iPhone app that uses ASIHTTPRequest to transmit data input by the user to a remote MySQL database via a PHP webservice layer. This works perfectly.

If the user presses the submit button the data should be sent regardless...the problem arises when there is insufficient bandwidth...rather than displaying some uialert to inform the user, I would like to implement some kind of function that constantly 'sniffs' for an internet connection even when the app isn't running (in main view) that ensures that the user only has to press 'submit' once.

How is this possible? Has anyone come across any tutorials/examples of anything similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this example application from Apple: [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)

It'll help you with some code to detect when the connection has changed.

Here's a link about backgrounding tasks. As you'll read, you can request additional time to complete a task, but it won't wait an infinite amount of time until it's complete. [Background Tasks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

Comment: +1. Reachability includes notifications on network status change. That's a better option than "sniffing", especially if you're inclined to then go try rolling your own "sniffer".

Comment: does this persist when the app is terminated? as in can i make sure that the data is sent if the submit button is pressed and then the app terminated or minimised?

Comment: I added to my answer with a link to Apple documentation about background tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Reachability API in conjunction with a flag of some sort that will perform the desired action once it detects that a connection is available.